# Running test calculations in DDP mode with multiple GPUs with PyTorchLightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I have a model which I try to use with trainer in DDP mode.

```py
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
import torchvision
from torchmetrics import Accuracy
class Model(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(
        self,
        model_name: str,
        num_classes: int,
        model_hparams: Dict["str", Union[str, int]],
        optimizer_name: str,
        optimizer_hparams: Dict["str", Union[str, int]],
    ):

        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.model = torchvision.resnet18(num_classes=num_classes, **model_hparams)

        self.loss_module = CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.example_input_array = torch.zeros((1, 3, 512, 512), dtype=torch.float32)
        # Trying to use in DDP mode
        self.test_accuracy = Accuracy(num_classes=num_classes)

    def forward(self, imgs) -> Tensor:
        return self.model(imgs)

    # <redacted training_*, val_*, etc. as they are not relevant>

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, labels = batch
        preds = self.model(imgs)
        self.test_accuracy.update(preds, labels)
        return labels, preds.argmax(dim=-1)

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs) -> None:
        num_classes = self.hparams.num_classes
        # Creates table of correct and incorrect predictions
        results = torch.zeros((num_classes, num_classes))
        for output in outputs:
            for label, prediction in zip(*output):
                results[int(label), int(prediction)] += 1
        # Total accuracy. This and `compute` are identical in 1 GPU training
        acc = results.diag().sum() / results.sum()
        self.log("test_acc", self.test_accuracy.compute())
        print(results) # This prints twice
```

and trainer

```py
trainer = pl.Trainer(
        gpus=torch.cuda.device_count(),
        max_epochs=180,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        strategy="ddp",
        auto_scale_batch_size="binsearch",
    )
```

However, I get as prints from `test`

```py
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5.],
        [0., 7., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 4.]])tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6.],
        [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
        [0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 3.]])
```

Also

```py
trainer.fit(model, datamodule=datamodule)
test_results = trainer.test(model, datamodule=datamodule)
print(test_results) 
# [{'test_acc': 0.18333333730697632}]
# [{'test_acc': 0.18333333730697632}]
```

where I would only expect single tensor to be printed. How can I make my calculations over all test predictions rather than by GPU and return the table I create in `test_epoch_end` from those predictions? I interpreted the documentation as `*_epoch_end` being executed only on single GPU and am quite lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use following techniques:

- `test_epoch_end`: In ddp mode, every gpu runs same code in this method. So each gpu computes metric on partial batch not whole batches. You need to synchronize metric and collect to `rank==0` gpu to compute
  evaluation metric on entire dataset.
- `torch.distributed.reduce`: This method collects and calculate tensors across distributed gpu devices. ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.reduce))
- `self.trainer.is_global_zero`: This flag will be true for rank==0
- What is best way to manually compute metric over test set? you should check [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/multi_gpu.html#synchronize-validation-and-test-logging)

Using mentioned techniques, you can compute metric over entire dataset and use `results` tensor after `.test`. Here is snippet:

```py
import os

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from torchvision import models, transforms
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10

from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, LightningDataModule, Trainer

os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER'] = 'PCI_BUS_ID'


class CIFAR(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, img_size=32, batch_size=32):
        super().__init__()
        self.img_size = img_size if isinstance(img_size, tuple) else (img_size, img_size)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.test_transforms = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize(self.img_size),
            transforms.CenterCrop(self.img_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        ])

    def prepare_data(self) -> None:
        CIFAR10(root='data', train=True, download=True)
        CIFAR10(root='data', train=False, download=True)
    
    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.test_ds = CIFAR10(root='data', train=False, download=False, transform=self.test_transforms)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.test_ds, num_workers=4, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=False)


class BasicModule(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet18(num_classes=10, pretrained=False)

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.model(x)
        return y, y_hat.argmax(dim=-1)

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        results = torch.zeros((10, 10)).to(self.device)
        for output in outputs:
            for label, prediction in zip(*output):
                results[int(label), int(prediction)] += 1
        torch.distributed.reduce(results, 0, torch.distributed.ReduceOp.SUM)
        acc = results.diag().sum() / results.sum()
        if self.trainer.is_global_zero:
            self.log("test_metric", acc, rank_zero_only=True)
            self.trainer.results = results
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = CIFAR(batch_size=512)
    model = BasicModule()
    trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=2, gpus='0,1', strategy="ddp", precision=16)
    test_results = trainer.test(model, data)
    if trainer.is_global_zero:
        print(test_results)
        print(trainer.results)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate `test_epoch_end`? How does the `reduce` work? Does it sync all threads at that code line and reduce the `results` tensor to the first GPU? I will test this today and accept if it works.

Comment: In ddp mode, each gpu run same code in test_epoch_end. So each gpu compute metric on subset of dataset, not whole dataset. To get evaluation metric on entire dataset, you should use `reduce` method that collect and reduces the `results` tensor to the first GPU. I updated answer too.

Comment: The `self.trainer.results = results` seems a bit hacky but this works.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I agree with you. If you want to use prediction results in other way, I think you should do in `test_epoch_end` or use `predict` method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but you can accumulate outputs in filesystem from all devices and perform calculations later.

Define `test_step` in LightningModule:

```py
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self.model(x).data.cpu().numpy()
    df = pd.DataFrame({'y_hat': y_hat})
    device = y_hat.get_device()    # this line binds out file to gpu
    df.to_csv(f"out{device}.csv")  # add code to do not overwrite file every time
```

Each gpu gonna write into separate file.